# Reading text from button and put into input and run

Tags: javascript, button, input

I am struggling with buttons and JavaScript.

I have a button which name is for example `button1` and I would like to put the name of it `button1` to input and click enter. I mean that I would like to send query for searching/sorting.

Here is with what I am done so far. It is working but only put text into input box without any action.

http://jsfiddle.net/9t7L4dmw/

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  var text = $( this ).text();
  $( "input" ).val( text );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>button1</button>
<button>button2</button>
<button>button3</button>
<button>button4</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search">
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do after the text is inside the text field?

Comment: Please, provide more details about what you want to do.

Comment: I would like to take text from button, maybe value="name1" and paste it into input search and execute it to proceed sorting of items

Comment: Where do you want to send it to? Do you want to do a AJAX request? You need to provide us with that you want to do exactly.

Comment: Yup, it is ajax request

Answer (score 0):

So when you click the button you want:

- the input to be filled with the button's name
- submit a form?

In that case wrap (at least) the `input` inside a `form` tag. In your JS submit the `form` after filling the input.

http://jsfiddle.net/9t7L4dmw/3/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("form").on('click', 'button', function () {
  $("#search").val($(this).text());
}).on('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault;
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  alert(data);
  // $.post(...);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method=post>
  <button type=submit>button1</button>
  <button type=submit>button2</button>
  <button type=submit>button3</button>
  <button type=submit>button4</button>
  <input type=search id=search name=search placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

---

About version without ajax

It doesn't work here in the snippet:

> Blocked form submission to 'http://stacksnippets.net/js' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.

but it's ok in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9t7L4dmw/4/

Comment: hmm It might work but I do not want to reload page. I've got simple input field and I just need to put there text and proceed it

Comment: @JarosławŁabuzek, then just send an ajax request. See no problem.

Comment: I will try to implement Your code. Hope it will work

Comment: is there option without adding {form} tag?

Comment: @JarosławŁabuzek, yes, there is. But there are no reasons to use it.